# How to increase amount shown elements report most viewed

Tags: magento, report

I would like to increase the amount of shown elements in the report
"most viewed articles". This is the report like
2015-01-01 => this 5 products have been viewed most

This is not(!) "recently viewd items" in Frontend. It's the report for the admin.

I expect it could be changed somewhere here:

```
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Report\Product
```

I tried `\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Report\Grid.php`
line 52 `protected $_subReportSize = 100;` instead of `5` but without any effect

Does someone know where to control the amount of "sub elements"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is actually defined in class `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Product_Viewed_Collection`.

File: `app\code\core\Mage\Reports\Model\Resource\Report\Product\Viewed\Collection.php`

```
class Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Product_Viewed_Collection
    extends Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Collection_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Rating limit
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_ratingLimit        = 5; //change this value

    .....

}
```

Comment: Thx(!) It's working great. Only problem is it's working on localhost but not on my dev system... But this is online a cache/index Iam missing somewhere. Thx!

update: It was the Compilation Process which was not updated. Working perfect:)